# shorthand array declaration causing error

Tags: zend-framework, array

This causes no error:

```
    $orders = array('position' => 'Position', 'name' => 'Name', 'price' => 'Price', 'sort_parent' => 'Featured', 'sort_child' => 'Product Group');
```

This does:

```
    $orders = ['position' => 'Position', 'name' => 'Name', 'price' => 'Price', 'sort_parent' => 'Featured', 'sort_child' => 'Product Group'];
```

Why is this?

Comment: what php version do you have?

Comment: @Marius PHP Version 5.3.10

Comment: That's the problem. Short array declaration has been introduced in 5.4. Please update your PHP version!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about PHP programming in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[] notation only work on php 5.4+

```
// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the short array syntax (`[]`) in PHP 5.3.
It is available starting with 5.4:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Ah, thought it might've been something to do with Zend.  I suppose I'll delete this Q.